# How do you show in a comic that in a scene with three characters only one of them can see one character?

Tags: creative-writing, comics

I have this scene where there's a character A that sees character B in the same scene, but character C who is right next to character A doesn't see character B.  How do you show that character C doesn't see character B without wasting any panel and not telling, but just showing?

I thought that just not explicitly saying anything could work, and make the people infer that character C is not seeing character C by not making character B interact with character C was the best idea, but how do you make sure the readers understand that?

Comment: Why doesn't A see B? If B is a ghost, I'm thinking half transparent... Maybe whatever reason A can't see B can be used to make it clearer? B is out of the line of sight from A, A is blind, etc.